# Run dependency parser on pre-initialized doc object of spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy, spacy-3, dependency-parsing

I am trying to incorporate spacy's dependency parser into a legacy code in java through web API.

All other components tokenizer, tagger, merged_words, NER are done from the legacy NLP code. I am only interested to apply the dependency parser along with the dependency rule matcher of spacy 3.

I have tried the following approach

1. creating a new doc object using https://spacy.io/api/doc#init.

```py3
from spacy.tokens import Doc
sent=["The heating_temperature was found to be 500 C"]
words=["The","heating_temperature", "was", "found", "to", "be", "500", "C"]
spaces=[True,True,True,True,True,True,True,False]
tags=["DT","NN","VBD","VBN","TO","VB","CD","NN"]
ents=["O","I-PARAMETER","O","O","O","O","I-VALUE","O"]
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=words,spaces=spaces, tags=tags, ents=ents)
```

2. Create an NLP pipeline with only parser

```py3
#can use nlp.blank too
nlp2 = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", exclude=['attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer', 'ner', "parser","tagger"])
pipeWithParser = nlp2.add_pipe("parser", source=spacy.load("en_core_web_sm"))
processed_dep = pipeWithParser(doc) #refer similar example in https://spacy.io/api/tagger#call
```

However, I am getting the following dependency tree

[dependency tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNRjz.jpg)

where every word is an nmod relation to the first word.

What am I missing?
I could use the tagger of spacy too if req. I tried including tagger using above similar method but all tags were labeled 'NN'

Comment: Instead of using pipeWithParser(doc), if i use nlp2(sentence). I get the correct output, but I need to pass in doc object, which is not allowed by nlp2(). The method called is similar to as given in similar example in https://spacy.io/api/tagger#call , so I assumed it to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parser` component in `en_core_web_sm` depends on the `tok2vec` component, so you need to run `tok2vec` on the `doc` before running `parser` for the parser to have the right input.

```py
doc = nlp2.get_pipe("tok2vec")(doc)
doc = nlp2.get_pipe("parser")(doc)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But tok2vec is included in the pipeline.

Comment: But not if you run `pipeWithParser(doc)` on the plain doc. You need `doc = nlp2.get_pipe("tok2vec")(doc)` first.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks. Since your latest comment adds clarity, if you could please add this comment to your existing answer too.  I will accept it.